# How to reply to a review using Trustpilot API

Tags: web-services, api, trustpilot

I want to use Trustpilot API to reply to a review.

I already have an `access_token` and this is my request :

```
POST https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/private/reviews/{reviewId}/reply?message={myMessage}&token={myAccesToken}
```

But this request always gets a **400 Bad Request** response.

In Trustpilot's API document, there is no specification about this.
https://developers.trustpilot.com/review-api#Reply to a review.

Can someone help me about how I can reply a review using TrustPilot API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using Reply-to-Review API:

1. Ensure you are using correct reviewID
2. You must provide access token in request, which you are already doing
3. The reply message is to be provided as request parameter in JSON format ( Kindly refer: https://developers.trustpilot.com/review-api#Reply%20to%20a%20review. )
4. Since you are posting the reply message in JSON format please ensure that

   A. In Request header "Content-Type" is set to "application/json"

   B. HTTP method type is "POST"

Any further issue, please contact support@trustpilot.com and I will reply you over there

Comment: I have tried a request like this: POST `https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/private/reviews/{reviewId}/reply?message:"{myMessage}"&token={myAccesToken}` doesn't work neither. Can you tell me an example of a correct request to reply a review.

Comment: The message:"{myMess‌​age}" that you are referring is a JSON and it goes with request header "application/json" ... I suggest you to use Google REST client ( https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo ) and send the snapshot to support@trustpilot.com and we would have it responded

Answer (score 4):

> This is a very late reply to the problem. But maybe someone will hit
>   the same problem one day.

What is missing is that the message should be posted in the payload of the request and not in the query parameter.

```
POST https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/private/reviews/{reviewId}/reply?token={myAccesToken}

PAYLOAD: {"message": {myMessage}}

Content-Type: application/json
```

The URL to the API doc has been changed to: https://developers.trustpilot.com/service-reviews-api#reply-to-a-review-